# Ubuntu Mosquitto not able to reload

Tags: mosquitto

I have faced issues while I want to reload my mosquitto services (MQTT) by /etc/init.d/mosquitto reload.

The MQTT broker doesn't start and I can see my MQTT Port is no longer in netstat.

So far, I only get this following error code that capture from syslog.

> segfault at 88 ip 0000000000423f5c sp 00007ffd0f26f530 error 4 in
>   mosquitto

I am pretty sure the configuration is good to go. However, I faced this issue like yesterday. 
I have tried restart the services and yes it worked. But not for reload.

Comment: It would probably help here if you edited the question to include: 1) the version of Mosquitto 2) your config file 3) what happens if you start mosquitto manually and send it a HUP signal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running with mosquitto 1.6.6 then this is a regression that has been fixed in the latest release (1.6.7).

https://mosquitto.org/blog/2019/09/version-1-6-7-released/

Comment: Hi there, thank for responding. Yeah, after the release update and upgrade the issue no longer there.